# Can't Use https on IIS on windows server 2019

Tags: ssl, iis, windows-server-2019

I have new server windows 2019 standard Edition, with IIS 10 installed on it I exported my wildcard SSL from my old server to the new server my website can work successfully on http only while on https it gives an error can't open and gives this error

https://www.screencast.com/t/zgpV7hnUw

I tried to create a new request and get a new certificate also get the same error, also I enabled SSL 3.0 in the registry but also no result.

also, strange behavior when I tried to test the SSL with ssllabs website I found the response successful with grade A

Any advice

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could be a firewall issue.  Does it do the same from localhost?

Comment: What's the URL for that screen shot? An error page without URL is useless. You might use tools like openssl https://www.feistyduck.com/library/openssl-cookbook/online/ch-testing-with-openssl.html to collect more information.

Comment: @tgolish I already added a firewall rule that allows port 80, 443. Also I have the same issue with localhost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for you all the problem is when I applied the registry that applies to enable ciphers and Tls 1.3 and Tls1.2 and disable Tls1.0 and Tls 1.1 on windows 2019. windows 2019 don't need to add any ciphers or Tls1.3 and tls1.2 protocols

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the issue you could try below things:

1)Open iis manager.

2)select your site-> bindings.

3)add binding with the below values:

type: https

IP: all assigned

port: 443

keep hostname blank

in certificate select IIS Development Certificate and click ok.

restart iis and site.

clear browser history and try to browse the site.